# Code Coverage: .NET Code Coverage and SonarQube VSTS Integration

Tags: .net, sonarqube, sonar-runner, sonarqube-scan

Does anyone know why Code coverage doesn't work with .NET (full framework) to integrate/publish result in Sonarqube ?
Here my scripts:

```
@ECHO OFF

MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe begin /k:"CalculatorConsole" /n:"CalculatorConsole" /v:"1.0" /d:sonar.cs.vscoveragexml.reportsPaths="%CD%\VisualStudio.coveragexml"
MSBuild.exe /t:Rebuild


"%VSAPPIDDIR%\..\..\Team Tools\Dynamic Code Coverage Tools\CodeCoverage.exe" collect /output:"%CD%\VisualStudio.coverage"
"%VSAPPIDDIR%\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\vstest.console.exe" "CalculatorConsole.Tests\bin\debug\CalculatorConsole.Tests.dll"

"%VSAPPIDDIR%\..\..\Team Tools\Dynamic Code Coverage Tools\CodeCoverage.exe" analyze /output:"%CD%\VisualStudio.coveragexml" "%CD%\VisualStudio.coverage"

MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe end
```

After run the script, no errors found and no code coverage published in Sonar!

Comment: Did you have a look at the SonarQube log (set sonar.log.level on debug/trace)?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Visual Studio 2017, recently SonarQube fixed a issue with the scanner not getting Code Coverage through Visual Studio 2017.

Here is the issue from SonarQube. https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARMSBRU-330

Version 3.0.1 was released on August 3rd.